# Rewriting an acceptable ADO query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2012, ado

I put this code together and from within SSMS it works perfectly.  Unfortunately, either ADO or VBA won't accept it because the sub query returns multiple items.  I'm not quite sure how to re-write it to get the same output.  What I need are the top 6 items in `pfsO` that share the same `[JOB_ID]` as items in `pfsJQ` that also exist in `sL`.  What's an alternative way of doing this?

**The error:**

> Description: Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

**The VBA code:**

```
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
constr = "Provider=sqloledb;data source=1.2.3.4;initial catalog=THECATALOG;user id=THEUSER;password=THEPASSWORD"
conn.Open constr

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandTimeout = 2
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "rt_sp_sys_nextOptics"
    Set rst = .execute
End With

If Not rst.EOF = True Then

i = 0

Do While Not rst.EOF
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Machine\NextOptic" & i & "SerNo")        '[PLC]OrderFulfillment_NextOptics[0].SerialNumber
    eTag.Value = rst(0)
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Machine\NextOptic" & i & "Stk")        '[PLC]OrderFulfillment_NextOptics[0].Stack
    eTag.Value = rst(1)
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Machine\NextOptic" & i & "Try")        '[PLC]OrderFulfillment_NextOptics[0].Tray
    eTag.Value = rst(2)
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Machine\NextOptic" & i & "Psn")        '[PLC]OrderFulfillment_NextOptics[0].Position
    eTag.Value = rst(3)
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Machine\NextOptic" & i & "XFP")        '[PLC]OrderFulfillment_NextOptics[0].PartIsXFP
    Select Case rst(4)
        Case Is = "XFP"
            eTag.Value = 1
        Case Is <> "XFP"
            eTag.Value = 0
    End Select
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Machine\NextOptic" & i & "RawPn")        '[PLC]OrderFulfillment_NextOptics[0].SerialNumber
    eTag.Value = rst(5)
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.tagDisplay.item("_Eventwatcher").EGroup.item("Machine\NextOptic" & i & "Label")        '[PLC]OrderFulfillment_NextOptics[0].SerialNumber
    eTag.Value = rst(6)
    i = i + 1
    rst.MoveNext

Loop

End If
```

**The SQL code:**

```
SELECT TOP 6 pfsO.[SERIAL_NUMBER], pfsO.[RACK], pfsO.[TRAY], pfsO.[POSITION], ff.[FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION], pfsJQ.[RAW_PART_NUMBER], pfsJQ.[LABEL] 
FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[PULL_FROM_STOCK_OPTICS] AS pfsO
LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[PULL_FROM_STOCK_JOB_QUEUE] AS pfsJQ
    ON pfsO.[JOB_ID] = pfsJQ.[JOB_ID]
LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[FORM_FACTOR] as ff
    ON ff.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] = pfsJQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID]
WHERE pfsJQ.[SELECTED] = 'True'
AND pfsJQ.[COMPLETED] = 'False'
AND pfsO.[COMPLETED] = 'False'
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT sL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[STORAGE_LOCATIONS] AS sL 
  WHERE sL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = pfsO.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
)
```

Comment: This cannot work perfectly in SSMS. If you are hitting the same datasource in SSMS as you are with ADO or VBA, you would get the same error.

Comment: Show your VBA code?

Comment: Aside from the Exists clause, I don't see a subquery.  And Exists won't throw that error.  My guess is your ADO query is not the same as this.

Comment: Slight detour....you have top 6 but no order by. You can't even be certain which 6 rows you will get.

Comment: @RandyMinder I added the VBA code.  Not sure it'll help, but that's why I'm here :)

Comment: @DeadZone Don't see a subquery?  `AND EXISTS (
  SELECT sL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[STORAGE_LOCATIONS] AS sL 
  WHERE sL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = pfsO.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
)`

Comment: @SeanLange I wrote it like that because I don't care what order they come in.  I only ever look at the first line item, the remaining five are used for predictive purposes.

Comment: OK but keep in mind that the "first" one is unpredictable also. :)

Comment: @SeanLange I do, thanks :)  In this case, it never really matters.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally this should be the same as a query with an inner join it it.  Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 6 pfsO.[SERIAL_NUMBER], pfsO.[RACK], pfsO.[TRAY], pfsO.[POSITION], ff.[FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION], pfsJQ.[RAW_PART_NUMBER], pfsJQ.[LABEL] 
FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[PULL_FROM_STOCK_OPTICS] AS pfsO
LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[PULL_FROM_STOCK_JOB_QUEUE] AS pfsJQ
    ON pfsO.[JOB_ID] = pfsJQ.[JOB_ID]
LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[FORM_FACTOR] as ff
    ON ff.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] = pfsJQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID]
JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[STORAGE_LOCATIONS] AS sL 
                                            ON sL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = pfsO.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
WHERE pfsJQ.[SELECTED] = 'True'
AND pfsJQ.[COMPLETED] = 'False'
AND pfsO.[COMPLETED] = 'False'
```

Then you don't have a sub-query so it can't give you an error about it.

Comment: I tried to join on that table earlier, but it was still spitting out optics that didn't exist in the [STORAGE_LOCATIONS] table, which is why I resorted to a subquery.  I'll try working on this again.

Comment: @Jaberwocky -- you have to use `JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN` if you want it to only include ones in the target table.